# Embedding Fonts Not Displaying in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I have had an issue with any fonts I have embedded not showing up whenever I view the webpage in Firefox on my Mac, and Chrome on a different PC.

I have asked a tech friend and he is insistent that it is down to the user not installing the font on their machine.  I said that I have embedded using Google Fonts and also uploaded a second font to the web server but he said that it is still down to the user not having the font installed.

Is this correct?  It would mean I have completely misunderstood what I thought I learnt about embedding fonts in my webpage if he is correct.

The site for reference (not that you will be able to see the fonts) is [here](http://www.tomrankinmusic.com/test/index.html).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is incorrect, but you have not properly implemented them either.

For Google Fonts you should firstly add the link to the font, either by putting it into the html like so:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Russo+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

or by importing it into your css.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Russo+One);
```

You then specify the font for the div in the css like so:

```
font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif;
```

**You have also a dead link to your own css.**

Comment: Hahaha!  I iz gd deesigner of webs!  Thanks for the info! :-D

Comment: What is the best practice?  I had followed the instructions from Google directly, but if this is better placed in the CSS then I will do that.  I would rather do that actually as it's a stylistic element

Comment: I would always keep it within the CSS myself.

Comment: Thanks for that Samwise. Appreciate the helps.

Answer (score 1):

The link to your MyFonts kit is broken. Fix that and they should appear. At the moment you’ve got:

http://www.tomrankinmusic.com/type/mercearia_antique/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css

but it should be:

http://www.tomrankinmusic.com/test/type/mercearia_antique/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css

The PT Sans font is working (at least in my Mac Firefox).

Comment: As with everyone else I have commented on thanks for the feedback!  Though, Chrome on the work PC doesn't display anything - I've found that it's system wide though so it looks like it didn't matter if I had implemented it correctly anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the font `PT Sans`, I do not see you actually embedding the font anywhere in your css.

You will need to provide a path to font and store it somewhere to be referenced like as:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'RieslingRegular';
    src: url('fonts/riesling.eot');
    src: local('Riesling Regular'), local('Riesling'), url('fonts/riesling.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

See here for reference:
http://bavotasan.com/2010/embedding-fonts-web-site-css-font-face/

Comment: Yeah I was pretty sure I hadn't implemented it correctly - this is what happens when you have a cat breaking your concentration. Thanks! UPDATE:I had used Google Fonts for PT Sans, so maybe I didn't mean embedding but linking kind of thing